# WordPress Error: There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

when I tried to create or edit page, it said "There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions." ! what can I do?
One solution I found that try to disable plugin so I have disabled all plugin one by one but still the error not resolved.
Can anyone please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: in your `wp-config.php` set WP_DEBUG to true: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` and then check. or check for an error_log file in your project root dir. or check webserver logs.

Comment: You may try (this plugin for debugging)[https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-debugging/#description]. Not sure if it will help or not.

Comment: Also, at first you may check the `wp-content/debug.log` file for any errors but make sure to edit the `wp-config.php` to turn on `debug` mode.

Comment: You may try (this plugin for debugging)[https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-debugging/#description]. Not sure if it will help or not.

Comment: check here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352723/how-to-fix-there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-your-website-please-check-your-s

Comment: Problem solved... Thanks every one for your positive response.

Comment: People who wanted to help are still lost, though. I am lost, I want to know how did you fix it. It is good practice that we share the solution that worked for us.

Answer (score 4):

**There are following steps you can refer to resolve such issues. most of times this issue occurs due to bad/partial plugin installation.**

- Always turn on debug.log file using adding below properties in
  wp-config.php file.

  ```
    define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
  ```
- Go to wp-content/debug.log file and check if you have any Fatal error there. If
  you find any fatal error related to any WordPress file it may be linked to any
  plugin.
- Go to plugin folder under wp-content and rename the plugin folder.
- Access the wp-admin page again you will be able to login successfully and issue
  will be resolved for you.

Comment: The log is even visible for non admin user. Is this fine?

Comment: @Akshith this debug file should not be visible to non admin users .. it contains critical information.

Answer (score 3):

You can also disabling your plugins to be able to login in your WordPress Dashboard by following this steps:

**Step 1 :** Log in to your hosting/server site. 
**Step 2 :** Find **wp-content** folder, then plugins. 
**Step 3 :** Rename the **plugins** folder to **plugins_old** to verify if your site is working by log in to your wp-admin site.

*Note: If it works, you can rename back the plugins_old to plugins then enable your plugin one by one to know your error.*

It worked on me, hopefully your problem was solved too.

Answer (score 0):

I once experienced this, and it was a plugin that mostly causes this. you can try to check the error_log or try to deactivate the exact plugin causing this.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Using wordpress here. I faced this issue when i purchased a domain and then i was trying to install wordpress. After installation it was giving this error. Although, just refreshing the page solved this issue. But bacause of backup uploading issue i was forced to install wordpress again and again until backup was uploaded successfully. Buy everytime i install wordpress i was facing same issue. With wordprss only two plugins were installed automatically. Akismet antispam and some titan security. I had to delete both plugins everytime. Just faced this issue again while edting on website. Search landed me here. When i heard about plugin, i disable and deleted akismet antispam and it worked. Must be some issue with this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue due to plugins.
Solution:
Login to the hosting provider site. Navigate to site plugin settings and deactivate all the plugins or particular plugin if you know which plugin caused the issue.
Refresh the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can also disabling your plugins to be able to login in your WordPress Dashboard by following this steps:

1. Log in to your hosting/server site.
2. Find wp-content folder, then plugins.
3. Rename the plugins folder to plugins_old to verify if your site is working by log in to your wp-admin site.

Note: If it works, you can rename back the plugins_old to plugins then enable your plugin one by one to know your error.

It worked on me, hopefully your problem was solved too.